# TypeError: unhashable type: 'csr_matrix' //encoding categorical data to make a multiple regression model with numerical values only:

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I'm a niwbie to ml and i wanted to implemented the multiple linear regression model.
i wanted to encode a 3rd column of my data using the X variable from my dataset to train a ml model for multiple regression. Here is the code:

```
#importing the dataset 
dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values


#Encoding categorical data 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder()
X[:, :-1] = enc.fit_transform(X[:, :-1])

X = enc.fit_transform(X).toarray() 
# Avoiding the Dummy Variable Trap
X = X[:, 1:]
```

[text](https://stackoverflow.com)
But this code is giving me a type error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anacondapaul\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_encode.py:170, in _unique_python(values, return_inverse, return_counts)
    169 try:
--> 170     uniques_set = set(values)
    171     uniques_set, missing_values = _extract_missing(uniques_set)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'csr_matrix'
```

what can i do here? is there a way of converting the csr_matrix its returning or another way around that exception?

#variable x which contains states

I printed x just after creating her, i got the csr_matrix or the sparse matrix. Yet I was expecting to get the labels of the 3rd column that contains the USA states.

I was expecting to get the encoded values of that 3rd column after 'the #Encoding categorical data'  code.

Comment: A fulll error traceback might help, but if `X` is object dtype array with these `csr` matrices, I doubt you can encode them.  A `csr` is a object instance with 3 main attributes, which are themselves numpy arrays.  Arrays can't be `hashed`, put into a set.  So the csr is doubly un-hashable.